# Can't set P74 of my PIC24F Development Board to HIGH

Tags: pic, pic24fj1024gb610, explorer-1632

I have a [PIC24FJ1024GB610](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24FJ1024GB610) Development Board ([Explorer 16/32](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/DM240001-3)).

I am trying to do a simple project where I would set P74 (PORTC RC14), and D3 LED at P17 (PORTA RA0) to HIGH.

This is the code for my project

```
#include "xc.h"

#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF 
#pragma config ICS = PGD2 

int main(void) 
{
    TRISCbits.TRISC14 = 0;//output
    TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0;

    LATCbits.LATC14 = 1;
    LATAbits.LATA0 = 1; 


    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

However, when I build the code and program it into the DB, I can see D3 LED to be lit, but when I bring a multimeter and try to measure the voltage at P74 I get a 0V. I thought maybe the Pin Header was defective and measured the voltage at the +3.3V pin with reference to GND and found out it was +3.3V.

I really don't understand, if there is nothing wrong with the code, or the pin header isn't defective, then why don't I get +3.3V at P74?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIM (MA240023) included with the Explorer-16/32 (DM240001-3) connects pins 73 & 74 of the PIC24FL1024GB610 controller to a 32.768KHz crystal located on the PIM.

These signals are not connected to the Explorer-16/32 circuitry.

To connect them to the Explorer-16/32 circuitry remove C11, C6 and X1 from the PIM and add wires from the upper pad of X1 to pin 74 and from the lower pad of X1 to pin 73 of the PIM connector.

You should also remove C15, C20 and Y2 from the Explorer-16/32 as well.

Also add R45 and R46 to connect the signals to connectors J48 and J49.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for pointing that out Dan, I changed the pins to P54 (PORTB RB15) and it worked. However according to the Explorer 16/32 schematics, P74 and P73 are connected to C15 C20, and Y2, and they are already soldered into the board, how can I remove them? By desoldering them?

Comment: Well yes it is important to remove C15, C20 and Y2 from the Explorer16/32 and also remove C11, C6 and X1 from the PIM board. then add R45 and R46 on the Explorer16/32. This is a lot of hassle. It really is best to not use P74 and P73 on the Explorer16/32 at all.

Answer (score 1):

The pin RC14 is an analog input by default so just add:

```
ANSCbits.ANSC14 = 0;
```

to switch it to digital.

Comment: This answer is wrong in two ways: 1) RC14 is not analog but an external crystal oscillator pin. 2) The solution proposed is not sufficient. The configuration words must be set correctly to enable digital I/O on the secondary oscillator pins.

Comment: RC14 is an analog input for comparator 3 [C3INC].

Comment: I stand corrected. Both RC14 and RC13 are assigned as analog inputs for comparator 3. Also keep in mind that the statement you suggest just sets the output data latch for RC14 to zero. I suspect that you actually wanted to recommend setting the ANSCbits.ANSC14 = 0.

Comment: @Dan1138 Yes of course. That was a typo. Sorry